# Recent dist-upgrade 15.04 volume up/down, lock screen, launch terminal not working

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, thinkpad

After dist-upgrade yesterday (Oct. 17, 2015) on my Thinkpad X1 Carbon (with adaptive function keys) the volume up/down no longer functions. As well I cannot `Ctrl+Alt+L` to lock or `Ctrl+Alt+T` to launch terminal. Any other X1 users notice this? Any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

This is sorted. I ran `gnome-settings-daemon` and restarted. Bob's your Uncle!